# global variable get null after being used in build state (flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to get a location weather by https://openweathermap.org/ free api. everything is working fine but when I try to use my global variables in my build method to show them in the main page of the application all the variables are reinitialized and get null. It seems using global variables is not such a good idea to deal with the variables .. right? then shat should I do?

```
String Lon,Lat;
 String cityName="";   //my global variable which I wish to show in the app
double? Temperature;

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: mainPage(),
   ),
  );
}

class mainPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<mainPage> createState() => _mainPageState();
}

class _mainPageState extends State<mainPage> {

  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    getLocWeather();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyScaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            cityName,   //cityName goes null here
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.blue,
              fontSize: 50,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void getLocWeather() async{
  Location location = Location();
  await location.getLocation();

  Lon = location.Longitude.toString();
  Lat = location.Latitude.toString();

  String url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${Lat}&lon=${Lon}&appid=${api_key}";

  http.Response response =
  await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    String data = response.body;

    cityName = jsonDecode(data)['name'];
    Temperature = jsonDecode(data)['main']['temp'];

 // I get correct outputs here in my print logs

    print(Lon); 
    print(Lat); 
    print(cityName);
    print(Temperature);
  }
 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getLocWeather` is a future method, It will take some time to fetch data.
Try `Future<void> getLocWeather() async{`  and

```dart
@override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    getLocWeather().then((value)=>setState((){}));
  }
```

Comment: thank you Yeasin for your reply, It solved my problem. 
I have another question tough, I've read that this format .then is an older syntax of dart and now its better to use await keyword with async functions. but when I change initState to a async function in order to use await keyword.. I got another error telling me its not possible to make the initState a async function!

Comment: you can make initState to async, if you like to use `await` you need another future method and then put it here. Also you may like FutureBuilder here

Answer (score 1):

Use future builder widget instead  to correctly render the widget once future completes, so you render the obtained value correctly.

see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are fetching the data in initState, and build is also called instantly after initState. As Futures take some time to execute, your build is getting called immediately after initState and using the values that are supposed to be initialized once the future call ends. To make sure that you only render the data once the data is fetched from the API, you can use the FutureBuilder from the flutter library.

Just wrap your body content with FutureBuilder and once the data is loaded show the data, else show some spinner or some loading screen or something to indicate that data is loading currently.

More on FutureBuilder here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I've also tested the FutureBuilder and it was interesting too.. as I understand the FutureBuilder execute the function we tell them in *future* parameter.. here: **getLocWeather()** . the problem is that in the second child of my column the text widget wants to show cityName variable but its null at the first place. although it has been called with  FutureBuilder at the first child of the column . in other words have I call the FutureBuilder again for every variable?

```
 @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MyScaffold(
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              FutureBuilder(
                  future: getLocWeather() ,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot ){
                    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                    else
                      return Text(Temperature.toString());
                    }
                  
              ),
              Text(cityName),
    
            ],
          ),
        );
      }

Future<void> getLocWeather() async{
  Location location = Location();
  await location.getLocation();

  Lon = location.Longitude.toString();
  Lat = location.Latitude.toString();

  String url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${Lat}&lon=${Lon}&appid=${api_key}";

  http.Response response =
  await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    String data = response.body;

    cityName = jsonDecode(data)['name'];
    Temperature = jsonDecode(data)['main']['temp'];

    // print(Lon);
    // print(Lat);
    // print(cityName);
    // print(Temperature);

  }
  else {

  }

}
```